# Run application in the background

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start the GroomDroid web server in Android but when it starts, a black window is shown.

[image]

I'd like to start this app in the background without that screen being shown.

I'm starting this app in the following way:

```
Intent webServer = new Intent();
webServer.setClassName("net.allory.groom","net.allory.groom.GroomDroid");
startActivity(webServer);
```

I also tried with `startService(webServer);` but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anybody help me with that ?

Comment: An `Activity` represents a user interface and cannot be started in the background. If you need to do background processing, then you have to write a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your background logic to a service, and when it's running create an ongoing notification.

Selecting that notification should start your activity (ui), and the service can communicate its data to it using a Handler.

Also, if you specify the `launchMode` of your activity to `singleTask`:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.YourActivity" 
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false" 
    android:finishOnTaskLaunch="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and on application start check if your service is already running (say you've already started the application, and now press its icon again), you'll be able to start the very same task, instead of relaunching your service and/or showing nothing.

This explanation might be not too clear, let me know if you need more details :)

Answer (score 0):

Lince,

Looks like the emulator. If you are using eclipse go to the 'Run Configurations...' and change the 'Launch Actions' to 'Do Nothing'

Do you want the app to always be headless?

Frank

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm not using eclipse, just a text editor. Do you know what would change in the code making the change you told me ? Yes, I want to run the server from my app in the background and them I'll send the user to a certain url.

Comment: Did you try commenting out the <intent-filter> for the main screen in the manifest xml?

Comment: If I comment that out, I get the error application not installed (trying in the emulator/sdk right now). BTW forgot to mention that I'm using phonegap. Anyway, I'm going to take a different approach. Thanks for your help Frank :)